# PostgreSQL how to write a stored procedure to get the First and last name from a table

Tags: postgresql

I want to write a stored procedure in PostgreSQL that get input parameters and then select data based on conditions using that input parameter values. How I can achieve this easily?

I only have to use the PostgreSQL stored procedure and and not function for this

Comment: If you want to return something you need to use a function, not a procedure

Comment: does PostgreSQL not supports returning data through store procedures

Comment: There are ways to do it, but it's a bit cumbersome and its not the "Postgres way". Postgres is not SQL Server. Use functions if you want to return something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PostgreSQL if we want to return result set in tabular format we have to use functions. they are best way designed to do this all functionality